# Google play developer distribution agreement. Where to view and agree

Tags: android, google-play

Google play developer console shows this message

```
THE GOOGLE PLAY DEVELOPER DISTRIBUTION AGREEMENT HAS CHANGED

The account owner for this account needs to agree to the new Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement within the next 8 days or access to this developer console will be blocked until the account owner agrees to the new agreement.
```

But I cannot find where to agree to it. I even took a look at https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html - i can only view it, but cant agree.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there another Google account that is set up as the owner of the Dev Console? When you log into the console with the owner account, you will be prompted with the new agreement and given the opportunity to accept.

Comment: That could be the case. I am just the developer, will refer to the client - Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That was right dcharms, it was from a different account and needs some sort of payment. I did'nt have access to that account at the point of original post. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: How can I find who is the 'primary account'?, I've created the apps and I'm not aware of any other accounts to my project...

Comment: @user1406269 The primary account is the one used to sign up as a Google Developer. From there, that account can give access to the Developer Console to other accounts.